# Are compactly supported Lipschitz functions dense in $L^2$ for some measures?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, compactness

I have been searching for such a statement in the book,https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/pdfbook.html but I can't find any! (Any reference for such a statement in that book would be most helpful!)

The closest thing I could find here is Theorem 12.50 on page 354 saying that w.r.t the Lebesgue measure the compactly supported continuous functions are dense in $L^p$. Does the corresponding statement about compactly supported Lipschitz functions with arbitrary measures somehow follow from this?

Answer (score 0):

Even stronger, $C^{\infty}$-smooth functions with compact support are dense in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ with the Lebesgue measure (where $1\le p < \infty$). Of course, the class of compactly supported Lipschitz funtions is a larger class than that of smooth, compactly supported functions.

For a proof of the above result, see for example Theorem 3 here: http://texas.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/f06/m5340_f06/mollifiers_approx.pdf

Comment: But I want a statement at arbitrary probability measures..

Comment: Apologies, I didn't read close enough. The same result should hold for any measure which is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure (this would essentially follow from the Radon Nikodym theorem). So it will hold for any probability measure that has a distribution function at least.

Comment: Any reference for such a general statement?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have one off the top of  my head. I think Terry Tao's lecture notes on analysis may have something of the sort: https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-117-tao3-epsilon1.pdf

Comment: Also given a function in $L^2(\mu)$ and an $\epsilon >0$ how does one construct such a $\epsilon$ close (in $L^2(\mu)$) compactly supported Lipschitz function?

Comment: Use convolution with mollifiers. If $\eta$ is a smooth function supported in the ball of radius $1$ about the origin with $\int \eta  = 1$, put $\eta_\epsilon(x)= \frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \eta(x/\epsilon)$. Then for any $f \in L^p(\mu)$ (so long as $1 \le p < \infty$ and $\mu$ is reasonable), we have $f * \eta_\epsilon \to f$ in $L^p$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ and $f*\eta_{\epsilon}$ is smooth and compactly supported.

Comment: So we know what $\epsilon$ to choose if we want $\vert \vert f - f * \eta _ \epsilon \vert \vert  = \delta $?

Answer (score 0):

Such a result should follow pretty easily from standard results. First, if $\mu$ is a positive regular Borel measure on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\mu(K) < \infty$ for each compact $K$, then $C_c$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$ for $1\le p < \infty$. Whatever proof you know for Lebesgue measure should work here as well.

Now take any $f\in C_c.$ Choose $R$ such that $B(0,2R)$ contains the support of $f$. By Stone-Weierstrass, there is a sequence of polynomials $P_k$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on $\overline B (0,2R)$. Take any $g\in C^\infty_c$ that equals $1$ on $B(0,R)$ with support in $B(0,2R)$. Then $gP_k \to gf = f$ uniformly on $\overline B (0,2R)$. We thus obtain a sequence $gP_k$ in $C^\infty_c$ such that $gP_k \to f$ in $L^p(\mu), 1\le p < \infty$.

Comment: So compactly supported Lipschitz functions are dense in $L^p$? You're only proving that $C^{\infty}_c$ is dense in $L^p$?